# How to scale up an image as follows?

Tags: jquery

I want to scale up an image upon a mouse click so that besides scaling up the point of the click stays under the mouse cursor (much like Google Maps zooming). I know how to do that in CSS3, but I want to do it in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

You'd do this with animate() and set the left/top position and width values.

**Here's a demo I've written as proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/7PzGQ/**

jQuery:

```
$('.imageHolder img').bind('click', function(e) {

    var _this = $(this),
        scale = 3;

    // Store default width
    if(_this.data('defWidth') == undefined) {
        _this.data('defWidth', _this.width());
    }

    if (_this.width() > _this.data('defWidth')) {

        // Reset image
        _this.animate({
            'left': 0,
            'top': 0,
            'width': _this.data('defWidth')
        });

    } else {
        // Localise clicked position
        var imgHitX = e.pageX - _this.offset().left,
            imgHitY = e.pageY - _this.offset().top;

        // Calculate position offset
        var left = ((imgHitX * scale) - imgHitX) * -1,
            top = ((imgHitY * scale) - imgHitY) * -1;

        // Scale image
        _this.animate({
            'left': left,
            'top': top,
            'width': _this.width() * scale
        });
    }

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="imageHolder">
    <img src="http://static.jquery.com/files/rocker/images/logo_jquery_215x53.gif" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: #000;
}
.imageHolder {
    position:relative;
    margin: 50px;
}
.imageHolder img {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could do it in CSS3, you could just use jquery's `.css()` function to accomplish the same effect.

See http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: What an answer! Lol :) No, I do not want to use CSS3. I want to do it without CSS3.